# WordPress, cron & time - does time on server affects plugins? How to fix it?

Tags: wordpress, time, cron, virtual-machine

I'm running WordPress on lamp install in a virtual machine. I frequently pause it, save snapshots, etc. Date and time aren't correct because of this and I think I noticed weird behavior of plugins that use cron. How do I fix my time and plugins? Maybe I should get time from an external location so it would be correct even though I regularly pause my machine?

Comment: I think this would fit better with serverfault.

Comment: you think so? how do i move my question there?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, running WindowsXP via VMware on OS X, Windows updates the system time a minute or two after I start the VM after a pause. If that happens, you should be able to manually trigger Wordpress cron and as a result WP and plugins should update. [Wordpress docs for wp_cron](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron)

Comment: i said lamp ;) (it's linux guest on linux host, actually)